# Login using Firebase Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have authenticated a user using Firebase Firestore database. I want to check if he is already logged in the app or not. I don't want to use the Firebase email authentication procedure.

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference allUsersRef = rootRef.collection("all_users");
Query userNameQuery = allUsersRef.whereEqualTo("username", "userNameToCompare");
userNameQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                if (document.exists()) {
                    String userName = document.getString("username");
                    Log.d(TAG, "username already exists");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "username does not exists");
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

This code will helpful you. Go through this code.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.